# Using Jquery and Ajax to overlay an image

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, jquery-ui, overlay

Hey all i am trying to find out how this site seems to be using Jquery to overlay the wood floors/ walls with whatever the user selects to a default image overlay.

Does anyone have any idea what type of jQuery plugin they are using to do this? It seems to just be calling an overlay-ed image on top of the default one?

http://boen.esignserver2.com/

Thanks!

David

Comment: I only looked for a moment, but they're using SVG to delimit the floor area. That's kinda neat.

Comment: Do you mean how the larger image on right side is being populated

Comment: @refhat: Yes, when the user chooses a floor it changes the floors image on the right (making it look like it was there all along)

Answer (score 0):

This Site is using ,  [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) Another JavaScript Library.

The larger Image on the right side is populated from Raphael.

Comment: Thanks! Can you be more precise as to what they use to transform the image? I'm not really seeing a demo of an image overlay.

Comment: They have a seperate function to do that, But I think if you browse Raphael or examples like this:
http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html
OR
http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html
You should get a good Idea of how this can be done.